I cannot view an answer to a question I posted
A week ago, I asked a question on how to invert an axis on spss. Jeromy Anglim moved that question to stackoverflow as it was more suitable to that site, so I made an account there as well so that I could view any answer directly. Today (22-9-2014) there was an inbox message about an answer to my question but when I pressed to see what the answer was, I didn't see any answer below the posted question. The answer as seen in my inbox started like that: "did you find the answer??? I couldn't do it on spss, so I 'm now using excel.."
The link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798763/how-to-invert-an-axis-in-spss
I would ask this in stack overflow but I don't have sufficient reputation for meta.
Is there something I can do about this?

One possibility is that someone posted an answer or a comment that moderators felt did not meet the minimum standards. As a result the answer may have been deleted.
In particular, an answer starting with "did you find an answer" looks like a good candidate for deletion.

Now that you put it that way, deletion seems quite possible indeed.

It looks like @jeromy was right about this.

Sounds to me like the answer was deleted. If the answer wasn't an answer (it stated with a question) then it was probably deleted. You could flag your own question and ask what the deleted answer said but you're unlikely to receive a response. 
If the answer was deleted then it didn't answer your question. The times this has happened to me (notified about an answer, looked and it was gone) I was also curious what it said, and the deleted answers were  always useless. 
